# Serverless WebSocket route responses

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` to create a WebSocket service, for which I am able to successfully trigger my WebSocket routes locally, using `serverless-offline` and for the deployed service.

The issue I am having now is responding to those WS events.

I am able to use `AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection` to respond to my local WebSocket events, though I cannot seem to get the `return` value of my handler to actually send a WebSocket event in response, as [these serverless-offline docs](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#websocket) and [these AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-route-response.html) suggest.

The `serverless.yml` route:

```yaml
  ws-custom:
    handler: handler.wsCustom
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: custom
          routeResponseSelectionExpression: $default
```

The handler:

```js
module.exports.wsCustom = async (event) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  console.log('WebSocket `custom` event!', event);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: `Hello, ${body.name}!` }),
  };
}
```

Invoking the function in my browser JavaScript:

```js
ws.send(JSON.stringify({ 'action': 'custom', 'name': 'kevbot' }));
```

The result is that my `serverless-offline` logs (or CloudWatch in the case of the deployed project) will create an event with the log successfully, but my client will receive no events in response.
Does anyone know how I can do this with the return value of the handler?

EDIT:

The problem seems to exist within my `serverless-offline` setup. I will attempt to get it working locally and will create an issue necessary.

Comment: I've created a pull request to fix the issue in serverless-offline
https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/pull/1064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important point to note when using WebSocket APIs and trying to return a response from your integration back to the client, as mentioned in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-routes-integrations.html#apigateway-websocket-api-overview-integrations-differences):

> For a route that is configured to use `AWS_PROXY` or `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration, communication is one-way, and API Gateway will not pass the backend response through to the route response automatically. For example, in the case of `LAMBDA_PROXY integration`, the body that the Lambda function returns will not be returned to the client. If you want the client to receive integration responses, you must define a route response to make two-way communication possible.

So, if you are using a proxy integration, then you cannot return a response back to the client. You would have to use the [AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html) method to communicate any data.

Alternatively, if you are using a non-proxy integration, then you can set up a [route response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-responses.html#apigateway-websocket-api-integration-response-using-console) for your integration.

Comment: This seems to only apply to HTTP APIs.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-responses.html seems to imply the opposite:  ` For proxy integrations, API Gateway automatically passes the backend output to the caller as the complete payload. There is no integration response.`  please excuse poor formatting...